# python2.7:A sample script ,in C partition it can run however in D partition it has AttributeError

Tags: python, module, urllib

I am learning python. Today I meet with a odd problem.

```
from urllib import urlopen

url='http://www.google.com'
f=urlopen(url).read()
print f
```

It is a sample script ,it can run if it in C partition however in D partition
it has AttributeError:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\urlopen.py", line 1, in <module>

    from urllib import urlopen
  File "D:\urllib.py", line 7, in <module>

    nettext=urllib.urlopen(strurl).read()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'`

I installed python2.7 and python3.1 in win7,and I run the script in python2.7's shell.

Comment: is it only urlopen that causes this behavior or is it all modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it works on `C:\`. It should fail either way. You're importing something from `urllib`. Your script is called `urllib`. The current directory comes before standard library dirs, so you import yourself. It's only because imports are "cached" (a second `import x` in the same interpreter process just gives a reference to the already imported module instead of loading it again) that this doesn't lead to an infinite loop. Of course your module doesn't have anything that's in the stdlib `urllib` package, e.g. no `urlopen`.

Comment: Seems reading questions before my morning coffee is a bad idea.  I'm going to agree with delnan here as I misread the error.

Comment: The OP's script is called `urlopen.py`, but there is also `D:\urllib.py`.  That's why it works on `C:\`.

Comment: Thank you!I am so stupid!I didn't check the "Traceback error" carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 many modules were reorganized.  One of them happens to be `urllib`.  To get the above code to work in Python 3 you would want to do:

```
import urllib.request
url = "http://www.google.com"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
print(f)
```

**Edit:**

You will also notice that in Python 3 you must use parentheses with `print`.  For a list of changes from Python 2.x to 3.x, see [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html)

If you are not trying to run this code in Python 3.1 but in 2.7 instead, then it seems your "D partition" is pointing to your Python 3.1 install, whereas your "C Partition" is pointing to 2.7.  Python 2.x and 3.x is typically not compatible (see above documentation).

Comment: He's running it with 2.7, so this might not be an issue (it could, but the issue he's having right now is a different one).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited my response to reflect both scenarios.